# Under which FPCR configuration ARM FP instructions conform to IEEE 754-2008 in AArch64 state?

Tags: floating-point, arm, ieee-754, standards-compliance, fpu

A simple question: under which FPCR configuration ARM FP instructions conform to IEEE 754-2008?

I suppose that IEEE 754-2008-conformirng FPCR configuration is:

```
- AHP (Alternative half-precision control bit): 0
- DN (Default NaN use for NaN propagation): 0
- FZ (Flushing denormalized numbers to zero control bit): 0
- RMode (Rounding Mode control field): 0 (Round to Nearest (RN) mode)
- Stride (This field has no function in AArch64 state): x (don't care)
- FZ16 (Flushing denormalized numbers to zero control bit on half-precision): 0
- Len (This field has no function in AArch64 state): x (don't care)
- IDE (Input Denormal floating-point exception trap enable): 0
- EBF (Controls the numeric behaviors of BFloat16 dot product calculations performed by the BFDOT, BFMMLA, BFMOPA, and BFMOPS instructions): x (don't care)
- IXE (Inexact floating-point exception trap enable): x (don't care)
- UFE (Underflow floating-point exception trap enable): x (don't care)
- OFE (Overflow floating-point exception trap enable): x (don't care)
- DZE (Divide by Zero floating-point exception trap enable): x (don't care)
- IOE (Invalid Operation floating-point exception trap enable): x (don't care)
- NEP (Controls how the output elements other than the lowest element of the vector are determined for Advanced SIMD scalar instructions): 0
- AH (Alternate Handling. Controls alternate handling of floating-point numbers): 0
- FIZ (Flush Inputs to Zero. Controls whether single-precision, double-precision and BFloat16 input operands that are denormalized numbers are flushed to zero): 0
```

Is that correct?

Comment: what did arm say when you asked?

Comment: @old_timer As I see, there is no one-fits-all statement regarding IEEE 754-2008 conformance. Instead, there are per-feature statements. For example: "Flushing denormals to zero is incompatible with the IEEE 754 standard, and must not be used when IEEE 754 compatibility is a requirement". Hence, `FZ16`, `FZ`, and `FIZ` need to be 0. However, not all FP features have these (or similar) statements. Confused (for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76414630/1778275)).